# Staring at a picture of a rainbow

Tags: halacha, rainbows

The talmud states that one should not stare at a rainbow (Hagigah 16a).

What about a picture of a rainbow- is this also not good?

Perhaps this question applies to other things one should not look at such as the hands of the kohanim during birkat kohanim or staring long at the moon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Rabbi Hillel Myers](https://www.hidabroot.org/question/217910) says that based on [Betzail HaChachma 2:18:4](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1808&pgnum=258) it would seem to not be an issue to look at a picture of a rainbow.

Chashukei Chemed Niddah 24b in the name of Rabbi Chaim Kanievsky Zatzal says that there is no issue with looking at a picture of a rainbow.

> שאין חשש להסתכל בקשת שבתמונה